# parse custom string to variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

Cannot manage to convert a string back to a variables in `Javascript`.
The string looks like:

```
"["variablename1 -0.0367046371102", "variablename2 -0.0208750199527", "etc"]"
```

Trying to access values (numbers) by doing:
`data.variablename1` and `data.variablename2`, etc.

Not able to split it the right way. **Can anyone help?**

Comment: `JSON.parse('["variablename1 -0.0367046371102", "variablename2 -0.0208750199527", "etc"]').variablename2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data can be split on the whitespace, you just need to iterate over your input, break up the input into key-value pairs, and add it to your `data` var:

http://jsbin.com/ledolekoje/edit?js,console,output

```
var input = ["variablename1 -0.0367046371102", "variablename2 -0.0208750199527", "etc"]
var data = {};
for(var inputs in input) {
  var tokens = input[inputs].split(' ');
  data[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
}
console.log(data.variablename1);
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you also have to post the code in the answer.

Comment: @yuriy636 Even if the link I posted contains the source? Okey dokey, I was not aware.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid JSON so you will need to stringify then parse to JSON
 something like this:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(["variblename1 -0.0367046371102", "variablename2 -0.0208750199527", "etc"]);

var json = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(json[0]);
```

http://jsbin.com/tayahadija/1/edit?js,console,output